# Undefined array key "after_sales_service"

Tags: php, laravel

I have a table of `prices`.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('prices', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignId('party_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
        $table->text('cash_lump_sum');
        $table->text('installments');
        $table->text('percentage');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}.
```

And I have three textbox field

```
number ++;
<textarea name="parties[`+ number +`][cash_lump_sum][]"></textarea>;
<textarea name="parties[`+ number +`][installments][]"></textarea>;
<textarea name="parties[`+ number +`][percentage][]"></textarea>;
```

This is my code summary.

Controller

```
if (isset($item['cash_lump_sum'])  && isset($item['installments'])&& isset($item['percentage'])) {
    foreach ($item['after_sales_service'] as $cash_lump_sum) {
        foreach ($item['installments'] as $installments) {
            foreach ($item['percentage'] as $percentage) {
                $party->services()->create([
                    'after_sales_service' => $cash_lump_sum,
                    'installments' => $installments,
                    'percentage' => $percentage
                ]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error

> Undefined array key "after_sales_service"

This error occurred in the following line

```
foreach ($item['after_sales_service'] as $cash_lump_sum) {
```

Comment: If you know _where_ and _why_ the error is occuring, it should be clear what the problem is?

Comment: I don't think someone can describe what's wrong here better, then the error message. It simply means, that your array key 'after_sales_service' is not set.

Answer (score 0):

Use [array_key_exists](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) to check the 'after_sales_service' exists or not.

```php
if (isset($item['cash_lump_sum'])  && isset($item['installments']) && isset($item['percentage']) && array_key_exists('after_sales_service', $item)) {
    foreach ($item['after_sales_service'] as $cash_lump_sum) {
        foreach ($item['installments'] as $installments) {
            foreach ($item['percentage'] as $percentage) {
                $party->services()->create([
                    'after_sales_service' => $cash_lump_sum,
                    'installments' => $installments,
                    'percentage' => $percentage
                ]);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I replaced this code, but it did not save in the database. and did not ant error